# How to login to this website using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I've been trying to login to a website with scrapy, but it doesn't work properly

```
import scrapy

class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'
    # allowed_domains = ['login']
    start_urls = ['https://seller.digikala.com/account/login/?_back=https://seller.digikala.com/sellerinvoice/']

def parse(self, response):
    # login = {}
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'email': 'email', 'password': 'pass'},
        callback=self.parse_item
    )

def parse_item(self, response):
    if response.body != None:
        print(response.xpath("/html/body/div/aside[1]/div/header/a/img"))
```

Comment: check this page in `DevTools` in browser (tab: `Network`). It sends data with names `login[email]` and `login[password]` but you send  `email` and `password`. BTW: You may even see this in HTML `<input ... name="login[email]" ...>` `<input ... name="login[password]" ...>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the email and password you'll need to take the value in `name` attribute. You can check if the login was successful the same way that I did, but maybe change the strings.

```py
import scrapy


class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'basic'
    # allowed_domains = ['login']
    start_urls = ['https://seller.digikala.com/account/login/?_back=https://seller.digikala.com/sellerinvoice/']

    email = 'yourEmailAddress@some.thing'
    password = 'yourPassword'

    def parse(self, response):
        # login = {}
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'login[email]': self.email, 'login[password]': self.password},
            callback=self.parse_item
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        if 'آدرس ایمیل صحیح نمی‌باشد' in response.text:
            self.log('Email address is incorrect')
            return
        elif 'نام کاربری یا رمز عبور اشتباه است لطفا دوباره تلاش نمایید' in response.text:
            self.log('Username or password is incorrect')
            return
        print(response.xpath("/html/body/div/aside[1]/div/header/a/img"))
```